# HTMLAgilityPacker How to get just href value when a contains other HTMLAttributes

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

II know the question sounds odd, and maybe my head is just to the point of exploding.  I am trying to fix some relative URLs to absolute URLs and the method below works fine.  Expect, my hrefs contain values of href.

Here is that example which is returned as att.Value from the HtmlAttribute att property `="yuimenubaritemlabel" href="/cgi-bin/Dis` :
[image]

```
public string FixLinksForWebsite(string Html, string baseURl)
        {
            var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(Html);
            foreach (HtmlNode link in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
            {
                string startLinkText = link.OuterHtml;
                HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];

                if (!att.Value.StartsWith("/"))
                    continue;

                att.Value = $"{baseURl}{att.Value}";
                htmlDoc.Text = htmlDoc.Text.Replace(startLinkText, link.OuterHtml);
            }
            return htmlDoc.Text;
        }
```

Here is the HTML `<li class="yuimenubaritem"><a class="yuimenubaritemlabel" href="/cgi-bin/DisplayMenu.pl?Reports&amp;id=-1">Reports <div class="spritedownarrow"></div></a></li>`
My logic is pretty simple, any help on how to get the href in a href using `HTMLAgilityPack` would be fantastic.

Here is a full HTML example

```
<HTML>
<body>
<li class="yuimenubaritem"><a class="yuimenubaritemlabel" href="/cgi-bin/DisplayMenu.pl?Reports&amp;id=-1">Reports <div class="spritedownarrow"></div></a></li>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: have you try this: ``link.GetAttribute("href")`` ?

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad yes the value is still the same, I don't understand why the label attribute is coming back with the href...

Comment: Could you include the URL to be scraped in your question?

Comment: @OleEHDufour I actually can't it's behind a paywall, but I included a full working HTML example